# Integers with prescribed divisor count

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, analytic-number-theory, integers, divisor-counting-function

1. Given an integer $n\in\Bbb N$ is there always an integer with $n^2$ divisors?
2. How to find such integers?

Comment: There is always an integer with $n$ divisors regardless of whether $n$ is a square, for instance $2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $m=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_s^{a_s}$ we have
$$
\tau(m)=(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_s+1)=\prod_{j=1}^s(a_j+1),
$$
where $\tau(m)$ denotes the number of positive divisors of $m$.
So for $m=2^{n-1}3^{n-1}$ we have
$$
\tau(m)=n^2.
$$
But indeed, $\tau(2^{n-1})=n$, so every $n$ appears as the number of divisors of some $m$.